# php echo image from another website

Tags: php, image

I want get images from another site by id, so I have 2 sites, in the first sites I stored the images, for example I want to show from www.site2.com with the following code:

This is my code of www.site2.com

```
$image = "http://www.site1.com/images/id/".$row2['acc_id']."/";
$images = glob($image."*.jpg");
sort($images);

            if (count($images) > 0) 
            { 
                $img = $images[0];
                echo "<img src='".$img."'>";

            }else{

               echo "No Picture !";
            }
```

on www.site1.com works this perfect, but this doesn't work on www.site2.com ...

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Is the image not showing? Is the ID incorrect?

Comment: glob is not supposed to work this way! how do you think it can read the directory of a "remote" server? it can't! It is supposed to be passed a local file path e.g. "/home/user/images/*.jpg" then it will read the files in that directory. The way around this is to create a service on site2 that returns a list of images to site1 (in JSON or XML). This will enable site1 to correctly know what files it is supposed to load.

Comment: glob can only work on the current server. It looks like your trying to scan all the images on a different server using glob which would be a huge security risk. Imagine if I used glob('*') on your website and it worked.

Comment: If you have the image name which won't change, why not use it directly, like `<img src='http://www.site1.com/images/myImageName.jpg'>`

Comment: No I have the same id's on the both sites. but my cms is in www.site1.com. I upload pictures from site1's cms.

Comment: Or skip glob, can I check from www.site2.com if www.site1.com/images/id/$row["acc_id"]/01.jpg exists ?

Answer (score 0):

```
 $image = "http://www.site1.com/images/id/".$row2['acc_id'].".jpg"; 
 $ch = curl_init($image);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
 curl_exec($ch);
 $retcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
 curl_close($ch);
```

First check weather you are getting image or not?

Comment: The problem is the poster doesn't know what images exist in the image directory so they are using glob to find the files. This really worn't help that much because they still won't know what images exist in the directory.

Comment: yes this is for the same it will return 200 if imag found and 404 if not.